# How to rotate any point by any angle?

Tags: javascript, math, rotation, geometry, 2d

Assuming `Vector2` is `(x, y)` I want to rotate it by center (or any point it's just a translation so I could do this) by any given `angle` given in radians.
My target language is javascript.

Comment: [Implementation of answer](https://gist.github.com/koziejka/17f89f9d81bee1eac3a46458f5211f77)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotation can be performed through a linear transformation ... a matrix multiplication.

Given an point `p = (x, y)` and a rotation angle `θ`, the resulting point `p' = (x', y')` is given by:

```
p' = R(θ)⋅p
```

where R(θ) is the matrix

```
       | cos(θ)    -sin(θ)|
R(θ) = |                  |
       | sin(θ)     cos(θ)|
```

The resulting decomposition is given by

```
x' = x⋅cos(θ) - y⋅sin(θ)
y' = x⋅sin(θ) + y⋅cos(θ)
```

Coding this in JavaScript is left as an exercise to the reader.